# string.Split for Span?

Tags: c#, .net

I was wondering how I may implement, or whether or not there are any workarounds, for a `sring.Split()` method, but for `ReadOnlySpan<T>` or Span in C#, because unfortunately `ReadOnlySpan<T>.Split()` does not seem to exist.

I am not quite sure how to achieve the behaviour I wish for. It probably could be implemented by leveraging the combined power of  `ReadOnlySpan<T>.IndexOf()` and `ReadOnlySpan<T>.Slice()`, but because even the support for `ReadOnlySpan<T>.IndexOf()` isn't too great (it isn't possible to specify a startIndex or a Count), I would prefer to avoid this entirely.

I am also aware that the problem with a `ReadOnlySpan<T>.Split()` method would be, that it isn't possible to return `ReadOnlySpan<T>[]` or `ReadOnlySpan<ReadOnlySpan<T>>`, because it is a **ref struct** and therefore must be **stack-allocated**, and putting it into any collection would require a **heap allocation**.

So has anyone any idea, on how I may achieve that?

***Edit: It should work, without knowing the amount of parts returned beforehand....***

Comment: A `ReadOnlySpan` is an *object*, not just a plain string, so I have no clue what such a method should do.

Comment: Suppose such a method did exist. How would you plan to *consume the results*? Perhaps that might indicate a better intermediate form than `ReadOnlySpan<T>[]` which would point in the correct direction for *what* to implement. I.e. would you be planning to access the elements sequentially or are you actually needing indexed access to the results?

Comment: An indexable collection would be preferable, but one could repurpose a sequential one, by using a foreach loop and increase an index for each iteration.

Comment: For `ReadOnlySpan<Char>` we have [`MemoryExtensions.Split()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.memoryextensions.split) in .NET 7. Unfortunately there isn't a `MemoryExtensions.Split()` for a generic type, but there's [some discussion here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/934) with some sample implementations.

Comment: I might be wrong, but as far as I can see `MemoryExtensions.Split()` will be released in .Net 8?

Comment: @user22782688 Oops yes, it's .NET 8 not .NET 7

Comment: As I have experienced similiar issues, on which I am currently working, I may be able to provide you with a sufficient implementation within a few days.

Answer (score 2):

As you have identified, such a `Split` method cannot return a `ReadOnlySpan<T>[]`. The split results must be consumed on the stack.

IMO, the most versatile design in this case would be to take a delegate argument, allowing the caller to say what they want to do with each result. The method can also return the total number of segments it has split the input into.

Here is an example:

```
delegate void ReadOnlySpanAction<T>(ReadOnlySpan<T> span, int n);

public static int Split<T>(ReadOnlySpan<T> s, T c, ReadOnlySpanAction<T> action) where T: IEquatable<T> {
    int index;
    int n = 0;
    var currentSlice = s;
    while((index = currentSlice.IndexOf(c)) != -1) {
        action(currentSlice[..index], n++);
        currentSlice = currentSlice[(index + 1)..];
    }
    action(currentSlice, n++);
    return n;
}
```

The caller can pass in a lambda and check the `n` parameter to get the result as a particular index.

With this basic design, you can easily come up with other variations. If you want a `List<(int, int)>` of all the slices, you can do:

```
public static List<(int, int)> Split<T>(ReadOnlySpan<T> s, T c) where T: IEquatable<T> {
    int index;
    int start = 0;
    var currentSlice = s;
    var list = new List<(int, int)>();
    while((index = currentSlice.IndexOf(c)) != -1) {
        list.Add((start, start + index));
        currentSlice = currentSlice[(index + 1)..];
        start += index + 1;
    }
    list.Add((start, start + currentSlice.Length));
    return list;
}
```

Or if you want the ranges of the segments to be written to a `Span<Range>` (similar to how the .NET 8 built-in [`Split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.memoryextensions.split?view=net-8.0) works), you can do:

```
// returns the number of segments found
public static int Split<T>(ReadOnlySpan<T> s, T c, Span<Range> destination) where T: IEquatable<T> {
    int index;
    int start = 0;
    var currentSlice = s;
    var n = 0;
    if (destination.IsEmpty) return 0;
    while((index = currentSlice.IndexOf(c)) != -1 && n < destination.Length - 1) {
        destination[n] = new Range(start, start + index);
        currentSlice = currentSlice[(index + 1)..];
        start += index + 1;
        n++;
    }
    destination[n] = new Range(start, start + currentSlice.Length);
    return n + 1;
}
```

Comment: This sounds promising! I have benchmarked your method and it outperformed the string.Split in both memory and performance. However it still allocates memory because if you need to do an operation outside of it, e.g.  sum up all the individual spans, then you'll need a closure. 
On Sharplab it looks like this:
`[CompilerGenerated]private sealed class <>c__DisplayClass0_0  
    {
        public int sum;

        internal void <Main>b__0(ReadOnlySpan<char> span, int n)
        {
            sum += int.Parse(span);
        }
    }`.  This causes memory allocation and overhead...

Comment: [Here is an example](https://sharplab.io/#v2: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=)

Comment: @user22782688 you cannot avoid allocating memory unless you know how many splits there will be. If you know how many splits there are, you can have the method output to a `Span<Range>` like the .NET 8 `Split`.

Comment: The Range-based implementation does not work for me! I have tests with three different versions to split a string or a Span<T>, but this one does not pass.

Comment: I cannot use this method either way, because I do not know my number of parts beforehand.

Comment: @user22782688 Actually, you do know the *maximum* number of splits. It is the case when the string contains nothing else but the separator character. The maximum number of splits is the length of the string plus one. If you always make a `Span<Range>` of at least that size, you can get all the parts> Of course, this will create possibly a lot of wasted space. Other than that, you can't have the cake and eat it too.

Comment: But that would require me to know how many separator chars are in my source though, what would mean an additional operation, what would mean, loosing any potential performance gain again - would it not?  However  I am really coming to like your preious implementation - Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Enumerable implementation below that results in `readonly ref struct`s that contain the start index and length of each segment (along with the source `Span`) with a method to return a `ReadOnlySpan<T>` for the segment (and is implicitly castable to such).

[.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/JhCp1z)

Usage sample:

```
foreach( var value in "0|1|2|3".AsSpan().Split( "|" ) )
{
    Console.WriteLine( $"{value}" );
}
```

Code:

```
public readonly ref struct SpanSplitter<T>
    where T : IEquatable<T>
{
    private readonly ReadOnlySpan<T> _source;
    private readonly ReadOnlySpan<T> _separator;

    [MethodImpl( MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining )]
    public SpanSplitter( ReadOnlySpan<T> source, ReadOnlySpan<T> separator )
    {
        if( 0 == separator.Length )
        {
            throw new ArgumentException( "Requires non-empty value", nameof( separator ) );
        }

        _source = source;
        _separator = separator;
    }

    [MethodImpl( MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining )]
    public SpanSplitEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return new SpanSplitEnumerator<T>( _source, _separator );
    }
}

public ref struct SpanSplitEnumerator<T>
    where T : IEquatable<T>
{
    private int _nextStartIndex = 0;
    private readonly ReadOnlySpan<T> _separator;
    private readonly ReadOnlySpan<T> _source;
    private SpanSplitValue _current;

    [MethodImpl( MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining )]
    public SpanSplitEnumerator( ReadOnlySpan<T> source, ReadOnlySpan<T> separator )
    {
        _source = source;
        _separator = separator;

        if( 0 == separator.Length )
        {
            throw new ArgumentException( "Requires non-empty value", nameof( separator ) );
        }
    }

    public bool MoveNext()
    {
        if( _nextStartIndex > _source.Length )
        {
            return false;
        }

        var nextSource = _source.Slice( _nextStartIndex );

        var foundIndex = nextSource.IndexOf( _separator );

        var length = -1 < foundIndex
            ? foundIndex
            : nextSource.Length;

        _current = new SpanSplitValue
        {
            StartIndex = _nextStartIndex,
            Length = length,
            Source = _source,
        };

        _nextStartIndex += _separator.Length + _current.Length;

        return true;
    }

    public SpanSplitValue Current
    {
        [MethodImpl( MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining )]
        get => _current;
    }

    public readonly ref struct SpanSplitValue
    {
        public int StartIndex { get; init; }
        public int Length { get; init; }
        public ReadOnlySpan<T> Source { get; init; }

        public ReadOnlySpan<T> AsSpan() => Source.Slice( StartIndex, Length );

        public static implicit operator ReadOnlySpan<T>( SpanSplitValue value )
            => value.AsSpan();
    }
}


public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    [MethodImpl( MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining )]
    public static SpanSplitter<T> Split<T>( this ReadOnlySpan<T> source, ReadOnlySpan<T> separator )
        where T : IEquatable<T>
    {
        return new SpanSplitter<T>( source, separator );
    }

    [MethodImpl( MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining )]
    public static SpanSplitter<T> Split<T>( this Span<T> source, ReadOnlySpan<T> separator )
        where T : IEquatable<T>
    {
        return new SpanSplitter<T>( source, separator );
    }
}
```

Comment: You're right, [foreach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/iteration-statements#the-foreach-statement) works for any type that has *... the public parameterless `GetEnumerator` method...* and *The return type of the `GetEnumerator` method has the public `Current` property and the public parameterless `MoveNext` method whose return type is `bool`.* -- which avoids the need to implement `IEnumerator GetEnumerator()`, which can't be done with a ref struct enumerator. I keep forgetting that enumerables are actually duck-typed to a certain extent.

Comment: Purely duck-typed enumerables don't play well with LINQ though.

Comment: LINQ requires the `IEnumerable<T>` and derivatives like `IQueryable<T>` as they're extension methods on that interface.  A struct implementing an interface requires boxing for use as that interface, defeating the purpose of using a struct (now that `record` exists) when that will be the common usage pattern and is why its a no-go for `ref struct`

Comment: Right, which is why I mentioned that duck-typed enumerables don't play well with LINQ.